# PHPExcel - How to load utf-8 file name to read

Tags: php, utf-8, phpexcel

I using `PHPExcel_1.7.9` and i try to load a utf-8 file name `$filename = "phố.xlsx";` to read it. like

```
$filename = "phố.xlsx";
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
```

and i get error like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open phố.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in ...\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:82 Stack trace: 
#0 ...\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(268): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('ph???.xlsx') 
#1 ...\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('ph???.xlsx') 
#2 ...\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\read.php(16): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('ph???.xlsx') #3 {main} thrown in ...\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 82
```

How can i load file have name is utf-8 thanks

Comment: Is the underlying filesystem on your server set to UTF-8? It doesn't look as if it is!

Comment: @MarkBaker i test that on my window8x64 and localhost? what should i do :(

Comment: Perhaps using [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [scandir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the filename as it's translated between charsets - or don't use non-ASCII characters in filenames, it inevitably leads to problems, especially between different operating platforms